# No module named 'config.settings' while deploying Django project on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings' while deploying a Django app on Heroku.

I'm deploying it from Github. Been battling for days with this problem but can't fix this.

The build is successful and so is the deployment but for some reason when navigating to the site address there is an application error.

But It's running fine on the local server.

Github code here: https://github.com/niloy-biswas/niloy-biswas.github.io

Folder Structure:

```
Root folder
- portfolio
* static
* templates
* __init.py__
* asgi.py
* settings.py
* urls.py
* views.py
* wsgi.py
- manage.py
- Procfile
- requirements.txt
```

wsgi.py -

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'portfolio.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Procfile -

```
web: gunicorn portfolio.wsgi --log-file -
```

Heroku log file -

```
2020-11-29T20:26:25.388554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn portfolio.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-11-29T20:26:28.090181+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-11-29T20:26:28.091131+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:45706 (4)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.091342+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-11-29T20:26:28.096462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-29T20:26:28.157113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362776+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362807+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362808+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362808+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362809+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362809+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362810+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362810+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362810+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362811+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362812+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362812+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362812+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362813+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362813+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362814+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362814+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362814+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362814+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362815+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362815+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362815+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/portfolio/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362816+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362816+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362816+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362817+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362817+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362817+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362818+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362818+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362818+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362819+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362819+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362819+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362820+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.362822+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings'
2020-11-29T20:26:28.363239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382575+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382577+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382578+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382579+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382579+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382580+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382580+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382581+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382581+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382582+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382583+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382583+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382584+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382585+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382585+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382588+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/portfolio/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382589+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382589+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382589+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382590+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382590+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382591+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382591+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382591+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382592+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382599+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382600+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382601+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382601+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382622+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382622+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382623+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382623+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382623+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382624+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings'
2020-11-29T20:26:28.382780+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-11-29T20:26:28.544449+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-29T20:26:28.544556+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-29 20:26:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-29T20:26:28.645845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-29T20:26:28.686408+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-29T20:26:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206007/importerror-no-module-named-config-settings-config-is-not-a-package